# stargazer in a .Rpres file

Tags: r, r-markdown, stargazer

I'm trying to make a presentation in an R Presentation (.Rpres) file and wanted to include a regression table using the stargazer package. I was using this cheatsheet as a guide (http://jakeruss.com/cheatsheets/stargazer.html). Using the regressions from the cheatsheet as an example, it works when I just use it in a normal .Rmd file (i.e. it looks just like in the cheatsheet), but when I try to do the same thing in .Rpres I get something that looks like this: [stargazer in .Rpres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVVXl.png)

The code was

```
    stargazer(output, output2, type = "html", single.row = T, omit = "quarter")
```